# next.js getStaticPaths list every path or only those in the immediate vicinity?

Tags: static, next.js

Using Next.js to export static pages, I get that in a dynamic route like `pages/[id].js` any path I put in the `getStaticPaths` section will be created. Cool.

Is it better to list every page:

```
getStaticPaths(){
  return (
    // some function to spit out a list of every possible page
  )
}
```

or

```
getStaticPaths(){
  return (
    // some function to return the next and previous page
  )
}
```

or does it matter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For dynamic routes example `posts/[id].js` `getStaticPaths` needs to define a list of paths so that `Next.js` pre-render all the specified paths at build time.

The function `getStaticPaths` needs to return an object with `paths` property which is an array with the route params and the property `fallback` which will be true or false. If `fallback` is set to false for any path that is not returned from the function `getStaticPaths` will not be pre-rendered hence resulting in a `404` page.

If you know all the paths that you need to render ahead of time you can set `fallback` to false.Here is an example..

```js
 // getStaticPaths for /category/[slug] where slug can only be -
 // either 'category-slug-1', 'category-slug-2' or 'category-slug-3'

 export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

   return {
      paths: [
        { params: { slug: 'category-slug-1'} },
        { params: { slug: 'category-slug-2'} },
        { params: { slug: 'category-slug-3'} }
       ],
     fallback: false // fallback is set to false because we already know the slugs ahead of time
   }   

 }
```

Let's says you have a route `/posts/[id].js` and ids coming from a database, and new posts are created every day. In this case, you can return the paths which already exist to pre-render some pages. and set `fallback` to `true` and on request, Next.js will serve a fallback version of the page instead of showing `404` page for the paths that are not returned from the function `getStaticPaths`, then in the background, nextjs will call `getStaticProps` for the requested path and serve the data as JSON which will be used to render the page in the browser.

Here is an example,

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
   const posts = await // your database query or fetch to remote API
   
   // generate the paths
   const paths = posts.map(post => ({ 
        params: { id: post.id } // keep in mind if post.id is a number you need to stringify post.id
      })
   );

   return {
      paths,
      fallback: true
   }   

 }
```

P.S. - When using `fallback` set to `true` you need to render some sort of fallback component in your `NextPage` component otherwise when you try to access the data from props, it will throw an error like `cannot read property ...x of undefined`

You can render a fallback like this,

```js
// in your page component
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();

if (router.isFallback) {
   return <div>loading...</div>
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, Sir.
I have one question, is getStaticPaths with fallback: true is good for SEO? because the thing that it renders is Fallback page which remove the SEO performance or google robots' ability to get the blog data for example.

Comment: For google crawlers, `fallback` will not negatively affect SEO performance. But for other crawlers, this may or may not be an issue for SEO. See this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12482) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. If SSR won't be run with best results with getStaticPaths, why in the first place getStaticPaths used rather than performance issues?
The point of SSR is to generate the content for the SEO.

Answer (score 0):

```
const paths = posts.map(post => ({ 
  params: { id: post.id.toString() } 
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.